# Prove that at least on of the numbers is positive

Tags: inequality, contest-math, real-numbers

Prove that for $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}$ at least of the the following numbers is non-negative:

$$(a+b+c)^2 - 9ab; \quad (a+b+c)^2 - 9ac; \quad (a+b+c)^2-9bc$$

---

If not all of $a,b,c$ are negative or positive then the problem is trivial, but I can't prove it when all of $a,b,c$ have the same sign. I tried to prove it using contradiction, assuming that all of the three numbers are negative.

**UPDATE:** When I tried to prove the statement, I had wrongly translated the problem, since it wasn't written in my native language. So instead of proving that at least of the numbers is non-negative, I was trying to prove that at least one of them was negative. Of course this doesn't hold, since for $a=b=c$, all numbers are equal to 0. But I'm interested whether it would also possible to show that at least one of the three numbers is non-positive?

Comment: From what contest?

Comment: @GEdgar Actually it's not from a contest, but from a math magazine that publishes contest preparing problems. Anyway it might have appeared in some contest, without my knowledge

Comment: @GEdgar Could you please read the update and give your thoughts on it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If they are all negative, you can sum all three inequalities and simplify to get
$$
(a+b+c)^2<3(ab+bc+ca)\iff a^2+b^2+c^2<ab+bc+ca
$$
but the last inequality is impossible because
$$
2(a^2+b^2+c^2)-2(ab+bc+ca)=(a-b)^2+(b-c)^2+(c-a)^2\geq 0.
$$
**Edit**: it's possible that all three numbers
$$
(a+b+c)^2 - 9ab; \quad (a+b+c)^2 - 9ac; \quad (a+b+c)^2-9bc
$$
are positive: just take $a=1$, $b=c=0$ so that each difference is $1$.

Comment: I had $3(a+b+c)^2$ after summing so then I divided everything by $3$.

Comment: Well, I feel embarassed. First since the problem wasn't written in my native language, so I somehow missed the negation in front of negative, so I actually spend an hour trying to prove that at least one of the numbers is negative. Also I didn't noticed that I had wrongly translated the problem when I was posting it to this site.

I guess it's tougher to prove that at least on of the numbers is non-positive. Actually it might not be true at all. What are you thoughts on this one? Actually I tried to sum all the inqeualities and I got: $(a+b+c)^2 > 3(ab+bc+ca)$, which clearly holds

Comment: @Stefan4024 I edited based on your update. Cheers.